# Arbitrary Inspection of Qt Stylesheet

Tags: c++, css, qt

I have several Qt stylesheets that look something like this:

```
MyClass
{
    my_color: #abcdef;
}
```

However, I recently moved MyClass into a new namespace, `ns`, which means that its corresponding qss classname is now "ns--MyClass", not just "MyClass". As a result, all my stylesheets are now invalid. Unfortunately, they aren't all under my control, so I cannot edit them manually.

So my question is: how can I configure `ns::MyClass` to use all the same style settings of `MyClass`?

Obviously, Qt has to parse the style sheet at some point. So if I could access the parsed style sheet and extract just the portions that affect `MyClass`, I should be able to add those portions into `ns::MyClass` via `setStyle()` or `setStyleSheet()`. But I cannot find a way to do this.

I am targeting Qt 4.8.

Comment: There is no facility to access the parsed stylesheet.

Comment: Why are you writing code for such an old version also?

Comment: @HamishMoffatt my bad, I got mixed up - I'm targeting Qt 4.8, not 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to patch Qt to add two methods to `QApplication`:

```
void setClassSubstitutions(const QMap<QString, QString> &);
QMap<QString, QString> classSubstitutions() const;
```

The substitutions would be held in the application's PIMPL, and you'd need to have the stylesheet mechanism use them. The entirety of the patch needed for Qt would be probably two dozen lines (or so I hope).